# how to add more than string in a variable in python

Tags: python, string, variables

am making a different program and in that situation it is like if there is any string from variable `A` in the Variable `B` it should print ok

```
A = "hello", "nice"

B = "this dress is very nice"
if A in B : 
    print("ok")
```

am getting error as -

```
[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.183 seconds
```

Comment: That `"hello", "nice"` is a tuple, a pair of 2 string, you want one string ? And the conditino would be `if B in A` no ?

Comment: did you mean `B in A`?

Comment: no actually am making a different project and the script is kind a same like this
so i want that if b has a string which is from variable a it should print ok

Comment: Then use `if B in A: print('ok')`

Comment: does `A = "hello", "nic"` should give ok ? Or only full match

Comment: Do you mean one of the elements of `A` is equal to `B` or one of the elements of `A` is a substring of `B`?

Comment: i want like if variable b has any part that matches a string in tuple A it should print ok

Comment: That would be the second part of Azro's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your requirement

> *if there is any string from variable `A` in the Variable `B`*

that should be : *if there is a part of `A` that is equal to `B`*, the corresponding code is

```
A = "hello", "nice"
B = "nice"
if B in A:
    print("ok")
```

---

If you want a possible partial match : *a word of `A` included in `B`*, use :

```
A = "hello", "nic"
B = "nice"
if any(word in B for word in A):
    print("ok")
```